# Run a PHP script with a header command via command line

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

I try to run a PHP script on my raspberry pi via command line, this part works fine. I use this command : `php myscript.php`

But I use a header command in this script, to access another script on another server like this : `header("Location: http://www.anotherserver.com/myscript")`. This script works also fine when I run it from my web browser, but when I run it from the command line, the header part will be not executed.

Do you have any solution for this problem ?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec ( instead of header to execute another script from the current script.